# Filtering a json field in presto to count occurences of integers

Tags: sql, presto

I have a json formatted field in a table like this:

[image]

I want to create a query to count how many times the numbers `0 to 10` appears in the key `employee_nps -> value`
If I try this query to count how many times the number 8 appears:

```
SELECT
    count(CAST(filter(CAST(json_extract(answers, '$.employee_nps') AS ARRAY(MAP(VARCHAR, JSON))), x -> json_format(x['value'])='8') AS JSON))
FROM
    table
```

I get the following error:

```
error querying the database: INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast to array(map(varchar, json)). Expected a json array, but got { {"value":["10"]}
```

**Note: sometimes `value` can be empty and in rare situations `value` can have string instead of integers so I would like to check if value is integer first.**
**My expected result is:**

```
0 - count 10
1 - count 120
...
10 - count 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`employee_nps` property value (i.e. `{"value": ["10"]}`) is not an `ARRAY(MAP(VARCHAR, JSON)))` but just a `MAP(VARCHAR, JSON))`, so you need to cast to it.

But if you are interested only in the `value` you can extract exactly it with `'$.employee_nps.value'` path. Then you can cast the value to `array(integer)` (note that it will handle conversion from number strings) and process:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (answers) AS (
    VALUES (json '{"employee_nps": {"value": ["8"]}}'),
        (json '{"employee_nps": {"value": ["10", "11", "1"]}}')
)

--query
select cardinality( --count number of elements in array
        filter(
            cast(json_extract(answers, '$.employee_nps.value') as array(integer)),
            i->i between 0 and 10 -- filter out elements not between 0 and 10
        )
    ) result
from dataset
```

Output:

| result |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

If you have json values for `value` which are not valid number arrays you can handle this cases with [`try_cast`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html#try_cast) (or [`try`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#id4) depended on required logic).

**UPD**

To count numbers you can use [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) to flatten the arrays:

```sql
--query
select num, count(num) num_count
from dataset
cross join unnest (cast(json_extract(answers, '$.employee_nps.value') as array(integer))) t(num)
where num between 0 and 10
group by num
order by num
```

Output:

| num | num_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |

Comment: Huge Thanks.  You code is working but Itś not the cardinality I need.  I need as output how many times each integer appear.  I need a table from 0 to 10 with the count frequencies of each of these integer.  Can you help me with this?

Comment: @pouchewar - use `unnest` - see the update. And for the future - please provide sample inputs and desired outputs and description so it easier to understand what is actually needed.